# Display File From Local Drive in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to display local Pdffile from D drive in a view of MVC along with other data.I have tried out Iframe and even added extensions for browsers like local links to display but of no use.I have been stuck with this problem since 3 days.I have tried out the following code.

```
<iframe src="@Url.Content("file:///D:/PdfsFolder/" + Model.FileName)"></iframe>
```

This works fine for me in IE but not working in Other browsers.When I try to open only the file using hyperlink it works in all browsers.My problem is to display it along with other data.please help me out If there is any other way to display that file in the View other than Iframe.

Comment: I can not repro the problem, it works for me in IE, Chrome & Firefox. Can you make a simple html-file and reproduce the behaviour. Maybe have some strange chars in the filename that different browsers handles differently?

Comment: @DanielStackenland when I inspect the page and try to render that link in the new tab it works fine..I am able to display that required pdf.

Answer (score 2):

you have to write a controller & action that will fetch the file and pass back to the response:

```
public ActionResult TestPdf()
{
    return File(@"d:\test.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

and now in your view you could use an iframe to point it to this controller action:

```
<iframe src="<%= Url.Action("TestPdf", "SomeController") %>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are to trying to attach a file from drive use root directory of project to pic the files like create a folder in your project put files their and try below code

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/UserImages/FileName.jpg") %>" />
```

Comment: @user1474602.I know that it can be done that way but my requirement is to obtain it directly from the local drive.

Comment: Its a Pdffile that has to be displayed

Comment: you have to write a controller & action that will fetch the file and pass back to the response:

public ActionResult TestPdf()
{
    return File(@"d:\test.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
and now in your view you could use an iframe to point it to this controller action:

<iframe src="<%= Url.Action("TestPdf", "SomeController") %>"></iframe>

Comment: @Rica working or not let me know when you are done ?

Comment: thanks for your solution I will try it and let you know

Comment: it's ok @Rica i think it will surely work let me know because it will be helpfull for others too.

Comment: Please mark a tick so that it is helpfull for others

Comment: Ok sure but can you update the answer as your answer lies in comment.I have taken some time to solve it.This is the code which I have written`<iframe src="@Url.Action("TestPdf", "Home", new { name = Model.FileName })" align="left" height="550" width="400"></iframe>` and controller`public ActionResult TestPdf(string name)
{
  return File(Path.Combine(@"D:\PdfsFolder",name) , "application/pdf"); 
} `